# Regex Exception in rows

Tags: regex, exception

Say i've got an regex:

```
"|<pizza><onion>(.*)</onion><tomato>(.*)</tomato></pizza>|"
```

This one matches a few rows and returns it (php: preg_match_all). Now I want to add an exception to (.*) in onion: onion may not have the value "default". How can I exclude this one?

Comment: Are you using regex to parse XML? If yes, please don't. Always use some kind of XML parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
~<pizza><onion>((?:(?!</onion>|default).)*)</onion><tomato>((?:(?!</tomato>).)*)</tomato></pizza>~s
```

Or the equivalent, but with the `x` flag enabled:

```
~
<pizza>
<onion>
(
  (?:(?!</onion>|default).)* # anything not containing `</onion>` and `default` 
)
</onion>
<tomato>
(
  (?:(?!</tomato>).)*        # anything not containing `</tomato>` 
)
</tomato>
</pizza>
~sx                          # enable DOT-ALL (s), and COMMENTS (x)
```

where `~` is the delimiter.

If your source has comments, `<!-- possible tags -->`, or can have an arbitrary number of  nested tags, I highly recommend using some sort of (X)HTML-ish parser instead.

Comment: "|<pizza><onion>(.*|!default)</onion><tomato>(.*)</tomato></pizza>|" wouldn't work?

Comment: @Kevin, what happens when you try?